# How to I get distance "value" from google maps distance matrix api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-distancematrix-api

I am autofilling an input field with the below which gives me distance.text value which is expressed in km but I'd like to get the distance.value for precision distance.

```
function getdistance(address){
    var dest_address = address; // Address enter by user
    var origin_address = document.getElementById('hall').value ; // Address where you need to calculate distance.
    var distanceService = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService(); // store Google Distance Service method

    // Call distance matrix services.
    // default parameters
    distanceService.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: [dest_address],
        destinations: [origin_address],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        durationInTraffic: true,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
        },
    function (response, status) {
        // check status from google service call
        if (status !== google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
            console.log('Error:', status);
        } else {
            // Response contain JSON.
            var error = response.rows[0].elements[0].status;
            $('#error').html(error);
            var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;
            document.getElementById("distance").value = distance;

            }
    });

}
```

I tried changing

```
var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
```

to

```
var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;
```

but still only getting the "text" value. 
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Sorry! changing the line to...

```js
var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;
```

...works. I just needed to clear my cache for the .js file change to kick in. =/ =/ =/